# Getting error in sql execution for creating table with foreign key constraint

Tags: mysql

When I execute the following SQL query:

```
CREATE TABLE course
(
   course_id varchar( 7 ) ,
   title varchar( 50 ) ,
   dept_name varchar( 20 ) ,
   credits numeric( 2, 0 ) ,
   PRIMARY KEY ( course_id ) ,
   FOREIGN KEY ( dept_name ) REFERENCES department
);
```

I get the following error:

```
MySQL said: Documentation

1215 - Cannot add foreign key constraint
```

Any insights to help fix this issue ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reference should be like `REFERENCES TABLE( COLUMN_NAME )`

```
FOREIGN KEY ( dept_name ) REFERENCES department( dept_name )
```

It will then look like

```
CREATE TABLE course
(
   course_id varchar( 7 ) ,
   title varchar( 50 ) ,
   dept_name varchar( 20 ) ,
   credits numeric( 2, 0 ) ,
   PRIMARY KEY ( course_id ) ,
   FOREIGN KEY ( dept_name ) REFERENCES department( dept_name )
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You have not included field from parent table to refer.

It should be:

```
FOREIGN KEY ( dept_name ) REFERENCES department( dept_name )
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify which column in your referenced table to match. Your query should look like this:

```
CREATE TABLE course
(
   course_id varchar( 7 ) ,
   title varchar( 50 ) ,
   dept_name varchar( 20 ) ,
   credits numeric( 2, 0 ) ,
   PRIMARY KEY ( course_id ) ,
   FOREIGN KEY ( dept_name ) REFERENCES department ( dept_name )
);
```